# Start cannot spawn child process: No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, slurm

Hi I get this message when I run my job in slurm what does it mean?
tensorflow/core/platform/default/subprocess.cc:304] Start cannot spawn child process: No such file or directory

Comment: Please show the example code (or a minimum reproducible error version thereof) so that folks have some context to give an answer for the specific issue

Comment: It might be happening due to memory leak. Attaching relevant thread for reference. Please provide complete error stack trace for further assistance. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71776183/11530462 .

Comment: @TensorflowSupport I am getting the same error. Any idea what is the missing file or directory?